# Test .py file in another file

Tags: python, testing

I have one .py file with my algorithm. In **init**(self) of this file I have some variables that need to be the same in all scenerios and 2 variables that I want to change for testing. I also created another .py file that is responsible to run my first file x times but every time with the same variables. My question is how should I properly create a testing enviroment for my first file to run it 10 times with different variables?

Sample of my .py file that I want to test in 10 different scenerios.

```
class A:
  def __init__(self):
      self.xsize = 50                
      self.ysize = 50                 
      self.max_tx_power = 200     # Variable to change
      self.min_tx_pow = 10        # Variable to change

  def alforithm(self):
      power_steps = range(self.min_tx_pow, self.max_tx_power + 1)[0::10]

  def generator(self):
      self.algorithm()

if __name__ == "__main__":
a = A()
a.generator()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of changes you need to make to the constructor of class A. Your new constructor would look something like this:

```
  def __init__(self, max_tx_power = 200, min_tx_power = 10):
      self.xsize = 50                
      self.ysize = 50                 
      self.max_tx_power = min_tx_power     # Variable to change
      self.min_tx_pow = max_tx_power       # Variable to change
```

If you need to run this in a new file to test, you would load this class as you would load a class from any module in python. Just make sure both files are in the same directory. Suppose your first file is util.py then the second file would look something like this:

```
from util import A
#Alternatively you can also use import util and call A as util.A(x,y)

for i in range(10):
    a = A(300,30)
    a.generator()
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to change your variables on every call to the `generator` function, it is in that call that you want to pass your variables.  Maybe your test file has this:
from PostClassA import *

```
for tests in range(10):
    b = A()
    power_steps = b.generator(200 - tests^2 , 10 + tests^3)
    print(f'Algorithm generated: {power_steps}')
```

and then shuffling around your class variables (and also fixing the syntax errors in your code) I ended up here:

```
class A:
  def __init__(self):
      self.xsize = 50
      self.ysize = 50

  def algorithm(self,max_tx_power, min_tx_power):
      power_steps = range(min_tx_power, max_tx_power + 1)[0::10]
      return power_steps

  def generator(self, max_tx_power, min_tx_power):
      return self.algorithm(max_tx_power, min_tx_power)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    a = A()
    print(f'Class A default test generated: {a.generator(200, 10)}')
```

I don't know what your function was meant to do so left it like it was.  Also dunno what the 'default' action should be.

*still getting Python legs and I'm sure there are more correct ways... my goal is to be clear